# ASP.NET - Securely Display PDF Without Caching

Tags: asp.net, pdf, ssl, cache-control

I'm looking for a way to display a PDF in the web browser *securely*. Something other than downloading the file, which would be stored in temporary internet files.

I was thinking of something like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41933/ASP-NET-PDF-Viewer-User-Control-Without-Acrobat-Re

But images would be cached. I want to be able to set `no-cache` and `no-store` headers on the PDF's data.

The idea I came up with so far would be to read a page out of the PDF into an image and deliver the image as base 64 embedded the HTML of the page (which would have the appropriate response headers). I anticipate that this would be a very slow way of doing things, though.

Is there a better solution, maybe even a nice ASP.NET control for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your .htaccess file

Code:

```
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"

</FilesMatch>
```

This should turn off all caching.

Comment: Asp.net that looks like IIS... But I get the idea. The equivalent in ASP.NET would be an .asxh file handler for the PDFs. Are you sure sending these headers would prevent it from being cached, though? How can you be sure the browser will display the document inline and not prompt the user to download it?

Comment: What did I write? lol I meant this looks like Apache, I'm using ASP.NET, IIS.